# Pass data from activity to service ? Android

Tags: android, android-service

How many I can pass data to `Service` by `Intent` . I am passing 7 data to `Service` but the latter two is `null` .

This code is in `MainActivity.class` :

```
    Intent Class = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class_Service.class);
    Class.putExtra("Url", URL);
    Class.putExtra("Username", Username);
    Class.putExtra("PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
    Class.putExtra("Mobile", Mobile);
    Class.putExtra("HQStudentID", HQStudentID);
    Class.putExtra("_SchoolCode", SchoolCode);
    Class.putExtra("_GroupID", GroupID);
```

And here is in my `Service` :

```
public class Class_Service extends Service{
    String Webresponse;
    String URL ;
    String Username;
    String PASSWORD;
    String Mobile;
    String HQStudentID;
    String SchoolCode;
    String GroupID;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handleStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handleStart(intent, startId);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    void handleStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        URL = intent.getStringExtra("Url");
        Username = intent.getStringExtra("Username");
        PASSWORD = intent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD");
        Mobile = intent.getStringExtra("Mobile");
        HQStudentID = intent.getStringExtra("HQStudentID");
        GroupID = intent.getStringExtra("_GroupID");
        SchoolCode = intent.getStringExtra("_SchoolCode");

        Log.i("test", "HERE : : :" + GroupID + "::" + SchoolCode);
    } 
}
```

All of parameter have value but `GroupID` and `SchoolCode` are `null` !!!

When I pass `GroupID` and `SchoolCode` from `MainActivity` have value.

Comment: before passing check its values

Comment: When I pass GroupID and SchoolCode from MainActivity have value.(before passing)

Comment: @PEDY: i agree with you try to test by sending `SchoolCode` value with `Username` key . then you are getting value in service or not
?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K . ok . whait.

Comment: Yes . thanks @ ρяσѕρєя K . In main Activity my GroupID and SchoolCode were int, now I convert them to String then pass them and get them .Thanks. please answer this question then I agree .

Comment: Just a suggestion. Always start variable names with small cap letters and use camel case when joining two words. Also some people put 'm' before member variables for clarity and better readability. Example, 'Webresponse' should be either 'webResponse' or 'mWebResponse'.

Comment: Amazing thing is that, you code is working even if you used `Class` as variable name. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things that may cause the issue :

1 : You are trying to send an integer and trying to get it as String on Service. Check the data types and fix if there is anything wrong.

2 : The data may be null. Check all datas before putExtra on Logcat to see all of them has some values.

Hope it helps.

Best,
Mack.

Answer (score 0):

If you`re passing an integer use intent.getIntExtras("tag") and for string intent.getStringExtra("tag").